# Walk/fly camera in sculpt mode

Tags: camera, sculpting, shortcut

Is is possible to use walk or fly camera in sculpt mode? Whenever I press Ctrl+F it calls for a brush strength manipulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. It turned out that I had to change the hotkeys to use the walk camera in the sculpt mode.